# BindingSource.Find with no column name

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a BindingSource as DataSource for a ComboBox. The BindingSource's source data is a `List<String>` which obviously doesn't have column names, but only a list of strings. The BindingSource.Find method expects a column name to search on, so I cannot simply use this function. I need to set the ComboBox to a specific selected item and since the source data is a BindingSource, I think it would be best to work with the BindingSource to achieve my goal.

How can I set the correct item in the BindingSource by finding on a specific string value?

Code example:

```
readonly List<String> _metaList = new List<String>();

...

while (reader.Read())
{
    _metaList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
}

comboBoxPartities.DataSource = new BindingSource(_metaList, null);
comboBoxPartities.DisplayMember = "Key";
```

And later on, I need to achieve something like this:

```
var bs = (BindingSource) comboBoxPartities.DataSource;
var i = bs.Find("?!!", lastProcessedTable);
((BindingSource) comboBoxPartities.DataSource).Position = i;
```

Comment: Use a Converter to Convert your List of strings to columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`List.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`BindingSource.Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.position(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<string> metaList = (List<string>) bs.DataSource;
int position = metaList.IndexOf("foo");
bs.Position = position;
```

If that string was not found in the list, the first item will be the current item.

Another method that you can use is [`List.FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows to search case-insensitive:

```
int position = metaList.FindIndex(s => string.Equals(s, "Foo", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Thank you! The first reply already did the job. My program processes large database tables, so it took some time before I knew it works good :). The default to select the current item is good for me, and the string isn't given by the user, but by myself from the DB, so it's always the same, so I don't need case-insenstive.